# Detect that textbox has one number and one upper letter

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Hi I need to use regular expressions in C# to validate a TextBox.

Regular expressions should validate that the textbox has one number and one uppercase letter

My code is:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
    ValidationExpression="[A-Z a-z 0-9]*[0-1]+[A-z]+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but it's not allowing

```
nameA123
```

Where is my error?

Comment: You mean at least 1 upper case or all letters must be upper case? Can you give an example of valid input?

Comment: What do you mean by one number and one upper string?

Comment: one number and one upper string ....

Comment: so two characters then how it allows `nameA123`? If you mean atleast one uppercase alpha and atleast one number means then how it allow the lowercase string `name`?

Comment: What should the textbox validate? Some kind of ID or username or is it a text box containing comments and things like that?

Comment: text box should have  atleast one uppercase alpha and atleast one number...

Comment: Yes, but does that mean that the input can be on two lines, three lines, more and can even contain characters like `ĘĖĮŠŲ`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/39), you can add strings to see if they match.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The lookahead `(?=.*[A-Z])` asserts that at it is possible to match some chars then an uppercase letter
- The lookahead `(?=.*[0-9])` asserts that at it is possible to match some chars then a digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches letters and digits
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: FYI: Added demo and explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would validates for atleast one uppercase alpha and one number and it won't care about any character including special characters.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cY1jR5/3)